# Twitter Bootstrap disabled class prevents button clicking

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a button look like a disabled button using bootstrap's `disabled` class.

But seems it actually disable it.

Actually I want to disable the button as well as show an alert on the click of that disabled button.

And far as I can understand, bootstrap `disabled` class is a just a normal css class like any other class, which has nothing to do with the functionality of the control

I am not sure if it does something in the javascript part to make `disabled` class control actually disabled.

Any work around for this.

Comment: Which Bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: as you can see, the click still works with `.disabled` on and bootstrap js and css on - DEMO at: http://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/uXKxq/

Comment: I have the same problem in FireFox and Safari, without Bootstrap. I set a "disabled" CSS class on a button, but still want to do something when clicking it. In Chrome this works fine and the click event is triggered. In FF and Safari nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

It would really be helpful if you could provide a sample of your code. Meanwhile, call the alert on the button click before you disable the button.